# How to stack numpy arrays with float values

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays with float values as below

```
a = np.array([.6,.5])
b = np.array([.2,.3])
print(np.stack(a,b,dtype=float))
```

When I want to stack them, I was expecting a result like

```
[[.6, .5]
 [.2, .3]]
```

But I am getting this error `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

How to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `np.array([a, b])` ?

Comment: stack takes (arraylist, axis, output), so it's just as the comment above states

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [numpy's docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html), the first argument should be a sequence of array_like.

You should then pass a list or tuple of arrays as the first argument like the following:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([.6,.5])
>>> b = np.array([.2,.3])
>>> np.stack((a, b))
array([[0.6, 0.5],
       [0.2, 0.3]])
```

Comment: Got it. Bad syntax mistake on my part. But got confused with the error message

Comment: The error message means it was trying use `b` as the integer `axis` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put parentheses around the arrays you want to stack:

```
a = np.array([.6,.5])
b = np.array([.2,.3])
print(np.stack((a, b)))
```

gives the expected result:

```
[[0.6 0.5]
 [0.2 0.3]]
```

When you look at `help(np.stack)`, you'll see that the first argument of `np.stack`, called `arrays`, expects a `sequence of array_like`.
This means, we should put some extra brackets around the arrays to make it a sequence.